# Heroku Cedar rake version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

What version of Rake does Heroku Cedar use?

My gemfile is at version 10.0.2 which the deployment code confirms is bundling on Heroku:

```
Installing rake (10.0.2)
```

But the app won't start, and running `heroku run rake db:migrate --app appname` or looking at the `heroku logs --tail` gives me  `/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake.rb:24:in 'require': no such file to load -- rake/version (LoadError)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rake` is not pre-installed on Cedar, you just have an empty container.  All the dependencies are brought in from your application (e.g Bundler).

Comment: That makes sense. I had 'rake' in my slugignore file, like an idiot.